# Create dynamic html from code behind

Tags: c#, html, .net, xml

I have a project that gets xml that represents a questionnaire that is very dynamic about the subjects and the questions inside(the type of question is the same).

I created an object that gets the xml and parses it to my .net object.

The next step is to build the aspx page (in .net framework 4.0) as the object which means that the HTML page will also have to be dynamic as well.
I am trying using placeholders but it is not the best way.

Does anyone has a different idea?

Example xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no" ?>
<Questionnaire>
  <clientID>1036</clientID>
  <QuestForm Desc="דוגמא" ID="1" Info="הסבר לגבי השאלון לדוגמא">
    <Subject Desc="כללי" ID="1" Info="הסבר לנושא כללי" NP="N" Num="1" TableRows="3">
      <Title Desc="מופע 1" ID="1"></Title>
      <Title Desc="מופע 2" ID="2"></Title>
      <Title Desc="מופע 3" ID="3"></Title>
      <Question Desc="טקסט חופשי" ID="1" Type="ט"></Question>
      <Question Desc="תאריך" FromDate="00/00/0000" ID="2" ToDate="31/12/2999" Type="ת"></Question>
      <Question Desc="שעה" FromTime="00:00:00" ID="3" ToTime="24:00:00" Type="ש"></Question>
      <Question Desc="מספר" FromN="1.00" ID="4" IntN="0.00" ToN="10.00" Type="מ"></Question>
      <Question Desc="בחירה" ID="5" Type="ב">
        <Answer Desc="תשובה 1" ID="1"></Answer>
        <Answer Desc="תשובה 2" ID="2"></Answer>
      </Question>
      <Question Desc="שפות דיבור בחירה מרובה" ID="6" Type="ר">
        <Answer Desc="עברית" ID="1"></Answer>
        <Answer Desc="אנגלית" ID="2"></Answer>
        <Answer Desc="רוסית" ID="3"></Answer>
      </Question>
    </Subject>
    <Subject Desc="חו&quot;ל" ID="2" Info="הסבר לנושא חול" NP="N" Num="2">
      <Question Desc="נסיעות לחול" FromN="0.00" ID="1" IntN="0.00" ToN="0.00" Type="מ"></Question>
      <Question Desc="מדינות מועדפות" ID="2" Type="ר">
        <Answer Desc="ארצות הברית" ID="1"></Answer>
        <Answer Desc="אנגליה" ID="2"></Answer>
        <Answer Desc="אוסטרליה" ID="3"></Answer>
        <Answer Desc="רוסיה" ID="4"></Answer>
      </Question>
    </Subject>
    <Subject Desc="נושא חברתי" ID="3" NP="N" Num="3">
      <Question Desc="כמה חברים יש לך" FromN="1.00" ID="1" IntN="0.00" ToN="100.00" Type="מ"></Question>
      <Question Desc="באיזה רשת חברתית אתה משתמש" ID="2" Type="ר">
        <Answer Desc="FACEBOOK" ID="1"></Answer>
        <Answer Desc="LINKEDIN" ID="2"></Answer>
        <Answer Desc="TWITER" ID="3"></Answer>
      </Question>
      <Question Desc="נולדת בארץ" ID="3" Type="ל"></Question>
      <Question CondID="3" Desc="ישוב לידה" ID="4" Type="ט"></Question>
    </Subject>
  </QuestForm>

  <Muamad Email="ORANI4U@GMAIL.COM" Event="28" ID="36130" Name="א אורן"></Muamad>

</Questionnaire>


 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                XDocument inputXml = new XDocument();
                string xmlParse = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\XmlInput\0022.xml");
                inputXml = XDocument.Parse(xmlParse);
                List<Questionnaire> questionnare = new List<Questionnaire>();
                questionnare = creator.BuildQuestionnaire(inputXml);

                dlSubjects.DataSource = questionnare.FirstOrDefault().Subjects;
                dlSubjects.DataBind();
            }
        }

        protected void dlSubjects_DataBinding(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            List<QuestionnnaireSubject> subjects = (List<QuestionnnaireSubject>)dlSubjects.DataSource;

            foreach (var s in subjects)
            {
                foreach (QuestionnaireQuestion q in s.Questions)
                {
                    switch (q.Type)
                    {
                        case QuestionType.Boolean:
                            CreateBooleanQ(q);
                            break;
                        case QuestionType.Date:
                            //questions.Add(CreateDateQ(element));
                            break;
                        case QuestionType.MultipleChoice:
                            //questions.Add(CreateTimeQ(element));
                            break;
                        case QuestionType.Number:
                            //questions.Add(CreateNumberQ(element));
                            break;
                        case QuestionType.SingleChoice:
                            //questions.Add(CreateChoiceQ(element));
                            break;
                        case QuestionType.Text:
                            CreateTextQ(q);
                            break;
                        case QuestionType.Time:
                            //questions.Add(CreateLogicQ(element));
                            break;
                        case QuestionType.UnKnown:
                            //questions.Add(CreateTextQ(element));
                            break;
                        default:
                            break; 
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        protected void dlSubjects_ItemDataBound(object sender, DataListItemEventArgs e)
        {

        }

        public void CreateBooleanQ(QuestionnaireQuestion q)
        {
            Label lbl = new Label();
            lbl.Text = q.Question;
            RadioButtonList rb = new RadioButtonList();
            //rb.DataMember = q.
            PlaceHolder ph = new PlaceHolder();
            ph.ID = "phBoolean";

            ph.Controls.Add(lbl);
            ph.Controls.Add(rb);
        }

        public void CreateTextQ(QuestionnaireQuestion q)
        {
            Label lbl = new Label();
            lbl.Text = q.Description;
            PlaceHolder ph = new PlaceHolder();
            ph.ID = "phText";

            ph.Controls.Add(lbl);
        }
```

Note that the input xml is for debugging and building the page for now.

I just started the code so I don't think that there is a lot of code to compare.

Comment: Show some code of what you are already doing that you feel is not sufficient? Lets see where you are at?

Comment: use XSLT, it's great to display XML data in HTML.

Comment: Better than post your XML would post your code.