# Load different ascx file to DataList

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have datalist item that i would like to load a different user control from code behind.

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="TextQuestion.ascx.cs" Inherits="QuestionnaireUI.TextQuestion" %>
<div>
 Name: <asp:Label ID="CategoryNameLabel" runat="server" 
          Text='<%# Eval("Description") %>'>
      </asp:Label>
      <input type="text" />
</div>
```

The line that supposed to add the user control to the alternating template

```
dlSubjects.AlternatingItemTemplate = Page.LoadTemplate("TextQuestion.ascx");
```

this idea is taken from the msdn library
but no matter what i cant see the user control in the page no even in the page source after the page has loaded.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Another dynamic way is to insert one Literal control into the DataListItem Template, On the other hand, wrap your control in an Empty ASPX page, and finally in code behind, Add IFrame into that Literal,

```
YourLiteral.Text="<iframe src='ExternalControl.aspx'></iframe>";
```

This will also give you the ability to pass a QueryString parameters.

Comment: I know that in the last few years less and less is using iframe. how this will effect my final result?

Comment: The Idea of bringing data from External control in code behind is less common than the IFrame, Even if you load the control into the DataList Template, you'll have 0% of control over it, I believe for most of scenarios you can do it in a less complicated way. anyway for both methods if the control is under the same application, Performance and Result will be the same.

Comment: Ok thank you very much for the answer. i will try now your way.

Comment: By the way this is in reference to this question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17924269/create-dynamic-html-from-code-behind, do you have any good idea on how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following method to get the html of control and print it into your datalist.

```
    public static string LoadControlToHtml(Page page, UserControl userControl)
    {
        string html = null;

        try
        {

            HtmlForm form = new HtmlForm();
            form.Controls.Add(userControl);
            page.Controls.Add(form);

            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
            StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(ms);

            HttpContext.Current.Server.Execute(page, sw, false);
            sw.Flush();
            string sa = sw.Encoding.GetString(ms.ToArray());
            sw.Close();
            html = HtmlHelper.RemoveFromTag(sa);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
        finally
        {
        }
        return html;
    }
```